# Run Time Error '13' Type mismatch when trying to loop through column

Tags: excel, vba

I get a type mismatch when trying to loop through column A with a For Each loop.

```vb
Sub timeStart()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim anchor As Range
    Dim i As Variant
    
    i = 2
    Set s = Workbooks("ER911 CALLBACKS SHEET").Sheets("Time Log")
    
    For Each i In s.Range("A:A")
        If s.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then 'ERROR OCCURS HERE
            s.Cells(i, 1) = Date
            s.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = InputBox("What is your name?")
            s.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 2) = InputBox("What program are you calling on?")
            s.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 3) = Time()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
For Each i In s.Range("A:A")
```

In this case each `i` is a Range object the represents the next cell in the sequence.

But then you are trying to use the range object as a row # in `s.Cells(i, 1)`.  So instead you should just use the range object you created:

```
For Each i In s.Range("A:A")
    If i.Value = "" Then 'ERROR OCCURS HERE
        i = Date
        i.Offset(0, 1) = InputBox("What is your name?")
        i.Offset(0, 2) = InputBox("What program are you calling on?")
        i.Offset(0, 3) = Time()    
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

As [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062576/excel-vba-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch-when-trying-to-loop-through-column/52062684#comment91075662_52062684) points out, you would be much safer to define your `i` as a Range initially `Dim i as Range` and then you would be sure to always use i correctly.  You would then need to remove your `i = 2` line as it not needed and would actually cause a different Type Mismatch error

Another suggestion would be to rename `i` to something more understandable so when reading this code 6 months from now, it is immediately clear what i represents.

Comment: Should also use `Dim i as Range`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It is working now. I was getting a 424 error (object required) but when I set I = s.cells(2, 1) it worked like a charm.

Comment: @AlexK. I did change dim I as Variant to dim I as Range.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply:

```
For i = 1 to N ' N = whatever the last row you wish to be
    If s.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
```

... and so on

or

```
Dim rX as range
For Each rX in s.Range("A:A") ' WARNING! there are too many cells here in the column, BTW
    If rX = "" Then
```

... and so on